# Rename changes in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

In the Google Drive UI, it reports on activities related to changes in the metadata (specifically, the Title changing).

[image: example of Drive UI]

However, looking at the results of using `revisions.list` on the file doesn't seem to generate a revision for the Title change. I don't see any other endpoint that seems to provide anything. The `changes.list` endpoint will show all changes in Drive, which is overkill to just get info for a file. Similarly, `changes.watch` will let me get notifications of changes, but I want to see the history of changes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/) gives you the same information of your screenshots